# UITableView selection changed event in Monotouch

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, xib

I created a custom hierarchy of views, somewhere in this hierarchy is a UITableView, with an outlet called `TableView`, so i can reach it from backend code.

I want to create and push a new view to the root viewcontroller's view stack when an item in that list is selected, but i can not find any relevant events on the UITableView.

All controls were defined using Interface builder in .XIB files

Am i looking in the wrong place?

thanks in advance.

Comment: you said "item in that list is selected". which list? and which item? please make this  point clear.

Comment: the question was, how do i listen if any item in a monotouch UITableView is selected.
But thanks for your time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, you are looking in the wrong place. To use UITableView's "events", you have to implement a `UITableViewSource` and assign it to your table view. The most common way to do it is in the table view's controller as a nested class:

```
private class MyTableSource : UITableViewSource
{

    public override void RowSelected(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {

        // Do something for the selected row

    }

    // Override both RowsInSection and GetCell methods!

}
```

You then set the MyTableSource class to the table view's Source property:

```
myTableView.Source = new MyTableSource();
```

Note that the UITableViewSource class does not exist in Objective-C. It is merely a MonoTouch class that hosts both UITableViewDataSource's and UITableViewDelegate's methods, making things a lot simpler.

Comment: Thanks for the clear answer.
The reason i got confused, is that i was using a UITableViewDataSource instead of a UITableViewSource from an appearantly outdated example.
(which was not appearant from my example code)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. You can still use both UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate, it's just that it needs some more code.

Comment: @DimitrisTavlikos: Thank you!  I was pulling my hair out trying to figure out why I wasn't getting events on the table itself or a delegate class.  But why do the table and table delegate classes have these events if they don't work?

Comment: @JoshuaFrank: Good to know it helped. Which events are you talking about? The events in UITableView are basically the UIScrollView's events which UITableView overrides.

Answer (score 1):

The RowSelected event happens in the UITableViewSource.